# Signalr Groups only send data to first connected client

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm using `SignalR` `PersistentConnection` on my server, and after updating from 0.53 to 1.0 I'm facing a strange issue. When adding clients to group via `Groups.Add(id, name)` and then sending some data to the group, only the first connected client receives data. This does not seem to be similar to other `Groups` issues I've found on stackoverflow and signalr github.Looking forward for the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Groups.Add` returns a `Task`. You should `await` the the call to `Groups.Add` before sending a message to the group that you expect the newly added client to receive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I'm not mistaking, this method didn't run asynchronously in beta version of `SignalR`